# Create a drupal 7 view for a content type created by all Author which was followed(flaged) by current user

Tags: drupal

I am using "Flag Follow" module for Favorites(follow) a user. I am following the users well. But i would like to create a view of a content type(blog) which will show all blog post list of those users which is followed(flaged) by current user.  Please help me !

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You must use a contextual filter to get the uid from URL and to add a relationship with followed users. After that you will be able to show content related with followers.